# Why are all of my <td> cells crammed under one <th> cell, instead of being evenly distributed among all <th> cells?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code is here:

https://codepen.io/ChocolateRoca/pen/qXdoNV

I believe this piece of code is the culprit, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
$('tbody tr'+row_counter.toString()).append(
  "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$employer']['$t'] +"</td>"+
  "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$title']['$t'] +"</td>"+
  "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$location']['$t'] +"</td>"+
  "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$employerorganizations']['$t'] +"</td>" +
  "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$typeofjob']['$t'] +"</td>"
)
row_counter += 1;
});
```

For a brief explanation:

I'm extracting data from a publicly available google spreadsheet, whose data I've converted to JSON so I can extract it to codepen.

The code is supposed to evenly distributed (td) cells under (th) cells, but all of the td cells are crammed under the first th cell. How do i repair this?

Comment: `tbody tr0` wut?

Comment: As @KevinB said, if you inspect the code you have <tr0> <tr1> <tr2> .... etc. They aren't valid html elements

Comment: Additionally, th elements denote cells, much like td elements. having a td element under a th doesn't make sense. it's likely the browser fixed that madness for you.

Comment: tbody don't have th, it have tr's. your code showing something and you are asking something else.

Comment: Take a look at the W3 Tables page to understand the general syntax for tables - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Intrepidity  did you checked the answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to edit this part of your JS :

```
  $(entree).each(function(){
    var current_tr = "<tr class=\"tr" + row_counter.toString()+"\">";
    var current_tr_name = "tr"+ row_counter.toString();
    $('tbody').append(current_tr + "</tr>")
    $('tbody .tr'+row_counter.toString()).append(
      "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$employer']['$t'] +"</td>"+
      "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$title']['$t'] +"</td>"+
      "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$location']['$t'] +"</td>"+
      "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$employerorganizations']['$t'] +"</td>" +
      "<td>"+ entree[row_counter]['gsx$typeofjob']['$t'] +"</td>"
    )
    row_counter += 1;
  });
```

worked for me..